# React: Prop value inside event callback not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a fairly simple case, I didn't think it would cause me problems. If Shift key is pressed I want to add a `e.preventDefault()` to my `selectstart` DOM event using React. Inoticed that the problem is that the `isShiftDown` doesn't update correctly. I don't understand why this is happening.

The `isShiftDown` isnside `handleSelectStart` function in `Paragraph` component is always `false`.
The same value inside `App` component toggle correctly.

All I have to do is prevent text selecting inside Paragraph if Shift is pressed. StackBlitz example may seem strange, but my real case much more expanded.

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uvd22x?file=src%2FApp.js)

```js
// Paragraph
const Paragraph = ({ isShiftDown }) => {
  let paragraphRef;

  const handleSelectStart = e => {
    console.log('Paragraph => handleSelectStart => isShiftDown =', isShiftDown);
    if (isShiftDown) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    paragraphRef.addEventListener('selectstart', handleSelectStart, false);
    return () => {
      paragraphRef.removeEventListener('selectstart', handleSelectStart);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <p ref={e => (paragraphRef = e)}>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  );
};

// App
const App = () => {
  const [isShiftDown, setIsShiftDown] = React.useState(false);

  const handleKeyUp = e => {
    if (e.key === 'Shift' && isShiftDown) {
      setIsShiftDown(false);
    }
  };

  const handleKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.key === 'Shift' && !isShiftDown) {
      setIsShiftDown(true);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp, false);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp, false);
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, false);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Paragraph isShiftDown={isShiftDown} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please put your runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Four reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future; and doing so makes it really easy for answers to reuse the snippet, keeping *that* content on-site as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried, but snippet not working. If anyone can fix it, I will be grateful.

Comment: `const Paragraph({ isShiftDown })` is a syntax error, which is why the snippet won't run. If you look in the actual web console when trying to run it, you'll see the details there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your unbinding cannot work, due to the fact that every time the component is re-evaluated, the event handlers' variables point to a new function. You should save a *reference* to it inside `useEffect` or simply use `useCallback` when defining the handlers:

```js
const handleKeyUp = useCallback(e => {
    if (e.key === "Shift" && setIsShiftDown) {
      setIsShiftDown(false);
    }
}, [setIsShiftDown])
```

Also, keyboard events should be binded at the `window` level object and not the `document`.

You should write it as follows:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export default function Paragraph({ isShiftDown }) {
  let paragraphRef;

  const handleSelectStart = useCallback( <---------- WRAP WITH HOOK
    e => {
      console.log("Paragraph => handleSelectStart => isShiftDown =", isShiftDown)
      if (isShiftDown) {
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    }, [isShiftDown])

  useEffect(() => {
    const ref = paragraphRef;

    ref.addEventListener("selectstart", handleSelectStart);
    return () => {
      ref.removeEventListener("selectstart", handleSelectStart);
    };
  }, [isShiftDown]) // <---------- ADD DEPENDENCY

  return (
    <p ref={el => (paragraphRef = el)}>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  )
}
```

### Explenation:

*Every time* `Paragraph` component gets called from `App.js`, it basically calls the `Paragraph` function, which has its own scope, its own `paragraphRef` and so on. React can be very confusing if fundamentals are not well understood.

Knowing the above, you will know if a piece of code inside the component is running in the scope of the latest iteration of the component, or a previous one.
How to know? Reading the code carefully and step-by-step simulating the flow in your mind, creating a vision of how it will act on the next time it is called. Knowing *JS* fundementals and knowing *React* is key to proper brain-parser which case save a lot of debugging time. it's all about the brain-parser.

Since you did not specify any dependencies for the `useEffect in` Paragraph.js`, it will only run **once**, on the first instance, and that's it.

You **must** re-bind the events every time the component re-renders, so everything will work with the last "version" of the DOM, as you intend, and not previous renders:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [isShiftDown]);
```

You don't really need to wrap the event callback with `useCallback`, but I would prefer to, in this scenario.

Comment: It is actually missing `setIsShiftDown` as a dependency and not `isShiftDown`, I forgot to correct his code all the way :) thanks T.J

Comment: Great answer! Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dahyup?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: *"a component will get a setter via props, and then it's indeed needed to do what I did"* Only if the setter passed through props doesn't itself come from `useState`. The point is that those are stable across the lifecycle of the component. But yes, if the parent is passing something bespoke, it might be needed.